# Mac Mini M1 on Monterey (just about) broke home sharing to Apple TV

Tags: appletv, monterey, home-sharing

I like to watch my (mp4) video files on my living room tv via an Apple TV (3rd gen).

I just swapped from Mac Mini M1 running Big Sur to a different Mac Mini M1 running Monterey (double the RAM and double the storage) and now using Apple TV to access media files is practically unusable.  It often won't see files or is super slow and then runs out of buffer.

Mac Mini is wired to network I see no network issues.  I've tried rebooting everything (Mac Mini, Apple TV, router, etc.).  I've tried turning off Home Sharing and turning it back on.  I still have old Mac Mini and it still works fine.

Any ideas on how to get Home Sharing working on new-to-me Mac Mini M1?

Comment: I have a Mac Mini M1 running Monterey serving files via Home Sharing and also via Plex, with no issues. So, I don’t think it’s the OS itself. Try setting up a new acct on the Mac and a few of the same vids to the TV app’s library. Also, do some speed tests on the drive in the new Mac, could be something wrong with it. And also try Plex. It’s a nice app, and will give you another comparison. If either the new acct idea or the Plex experiment works, might be a corruption in your TV library, maybe delete/move it, and make a new one.